does pac4j SAML support signing key rotation
Does pac4j SAML support automatic token signing cert/key rotation?
if the answer is yes, is it configurable and what is default setting ?
we are using pac4j 4.5.7
thanks
Eyal

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
